# Подбор ресурсов для разных экранов для android приложения

Tags: java, android-studio, ресурсы

Здравствуйте, я начинающий android-разработчик. У меня имеется приложение, которое я хочу адаптировать под различные устройства. На эмуляторе используются mdpi ресурсы (5.1 WVGA), получается это https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJzpC.jpg (кнопки должны быть больше). Как решать данную проблему? При запуске на эмуляторе с меньшей диагональю все работает отлично.

Comment: Для изображений здесь есть собственный ресурс, пользуйтесь Ctrl-G.
Вы уверены, что проблема не в коде? Если нет, добавте в вопрос фрагменты вашего кода.

Comment: Не думаю, для всех изображений используется wrap_content (как weight и height). Получается что на больших экранах используются маленькие картинки-а почему так-в этом состоит вопрос.